# How to pass data from one page to another by onclick into a specific list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a program that allows users to create lists and save data inside lists. I have created two pages first page has the data and second page where you create a list. Let me tell you the problem, as if I create three lists and I would like to save the data in the second list by onclick, but the data is saved in all three lists.

Here is the first page which has data

page1.js

items and domore are the data for now.

```
const apiSchema = 'http://localhost:5000/api/Schema'
const TableBody = document.querySelector('#recieve-info');
let items = 'hey'
let domore = 'hi'
TableBody.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    let SaveButtonPressed = e.target.id == 'save-button'
    if (SaveButtonPressed) {
        let data = { items, domore }
        let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
        
        const response = await fetch(apiSchema, options);
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
    }
});

// GETTING list value FROM THE LIST PAGE 
const ItemConnectionUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/item/Schema';
let Output = '';

const renderDataItem = (datas) => {
    datas.forEach((Item) => {
        Output += `
        <tr class = "tr">
            <td name = "dynamicValue">${Item.data}</td> 
            <td name = "button"> <button class="Save-Button" id="save-button">Save</button> </td>
        </tr>`
    });
    TableBody.innerHTML = Output;
}

fetch(ItemConnectionUrl)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => renderDataItem(data));
```

Here is the model of page1

model1.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const api_list = new Schema({
    data: Array
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('api_list', api_list);
```

Here is the route of first page

route1.js

```
 // GET REQUEST '/api/Schema'
    router.get('/', async (req,res) => {
        try{
            const apis = await apiSchema.find();
            if(!apis) throw Error('No list');
    
            res.status(200).json(apis);
        }catch(err){
            res.status(400).json({msg : err});
        }
    });
    
    
    //POST REQUEST '/api/Schema'
    router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        let data =req.body
        const apilist = new apiSchema({data});
        console.log(apilist)
    
        try{
            const api = await apilist.save();
            if(!api) throw Error('Something went wrong while saving to list');
    
            res.status(200).json({api});
    
        } catch(err) {
            res.status(400).json({msg : err});

}
    });
```

[[image: Here is the screenshot of first page]]

Here is the screenshot of first page (list1, list2, list3) come from the lists page. I would like that if i click the second list button I want the data to be saved in the second list on the lists page.

Here is the second page where you create a list (lists page)

page2.js

```
const TableBody = document.querySelector('#tableBody');
const addItemForm = document.querySelector('.add-item-form')
const titleValue = document.querySelector('#title');
const addButton = document.querySelector('#add')
let Output = '';
const ItemConnectionUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/item/Schema'

const renderDataItem = (datas) => {
    datas.forEach((Item) => {
        Output += `<tr data-id=${Item._id}>
        <td scope="row"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></td>
        <td class="ele">${Item.data}</td>

        <td class="table-buttons">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary open-modal" id="open" data-modal-target="#modal" id="passvaluebutton" onclick = "ShowPopUp()" value="click">Open</button>
        </td>
        
        <td class="table-buttons"><button class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-warning" id="edit_btn"><i class="far fa-edit icon icon-modify"></i></button></td> 

        <td class="table-buttons"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-btn" id="delete_btns"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt icon icon-modify"></i></button></td>


      </tr>`
    });
    TableBody.innerHTML = Output
}

// Create - Read item 
// METHOD : GET
fetch(ItemConnectionUrl)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => renderDataItem(data));


// SELECTING TABLE 
TableBody.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 let deleteButton = e.target.id == 'delete_btns'
 let editButton = e.target.id == 'edit_btn'

 let id = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.id;

//DELETE-- Remove existing value
// METHOD: Delete
if(deleteButton){
  fetch(`${ItemConnectionUrl}/${id}`, {
    method : 'DELETE',
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(() => location.reload())
}

//EDIT-- Remove existing value
// METHOD: Patch
if(editButton){
  const edit = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
  let dataContent = edit.querySelector('.ele').textContent;

  titleValue.value = dataContent;
  addButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(`${ItemConnectionUrl}/${id}`,{
      method : 'PATCH',
      headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
      },
      body : JSON.stringify({
        data : titleValue.value
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(() => location.reload())
  });
};

});

// Create - Inset new item 
// METHOD : POST
addItemForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(ItemConnectionUrl, {
    method : 'POST',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body : JSON.stringify({
      data : titleValue.value
    })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    const dataArr = [];
    dataArr.push(data)
    renderDataItem(dataArr)
  });

  // RESET INPUT VALUE TO EMPTY
  titleValue.value=''
});


//Here is where you get the data from page1

const apiSchema = 'http://localhost:5000/api/schema'
async function ParaG() {
  const response = await fetch(apiSchema);
  const data  = await response.json();
  console.log(data);

  for (let item of data) {
    let info = item.data[0]
    const para = document.querySelector('.Second-Para');
    para.innerHTML += `${info.items}, ${info.domore}`
  }

}
```

Here is the model of page 2

model2.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const item_list = new Schema({
        data : String
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('item_list', item_list);
```

Here is the route 2 route2.js

```
// GET REQUEST '/item/Schema'
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

        res.status(200).json(items);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
    }
});

// GET REQUEST '/item/Schema/:id' GET A SPECIFIC ID
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const items = await itemSchema.findById(req.params.id);
        if (!items) throw Error('No list');

        res.status(200).json(items);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
    }
});


// POST REQUEST '/item/Schema'
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const itemlist = new itemSchema(req.body);

    try {
        const item = await itemlist.save();
        if (!item) throw Error('Something went wrong while saving to list');

        res.status(200).json(item);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
    }
});

// DELETE REQUEST '/item/Schema/:id'
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const item = await itemSchema.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

        if (!item) throw Error('no list found');
        res.status(200).json({ success: true })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
    }
});

// UPDATE REQUEST '/item/Schema/:id'
router.patch('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const item = await itemSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body);

        if (!item) throw Error('Something went wrong while updating the list');
        res.status(200).json({ success: true })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
    }
});

// GET REQUEST '/item/Schema TRANSFER TO THE BOOKS PAGE'
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const items = await itemSchema.find();
        if (!items) throw Error('No list');

        res.json(items)

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
    }
});
```

[image: All lists are linked to a pop up modal where i want the data to be saved]
All lists are linked to a pop up modal where i want the data to be saved

[image: screenshot of second page where i want the data to be saved]
screenshot of second page where i want the data to be saved.